# Remove the values in pandas column list that match another column in that same row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas df where one of the columns is made up of lists. I want to remove the values in that list that match another column in that same row. Please note sometimes the 'similar_ids' is empty or only has one value. Example is below:

original

```
ID     similar_ids 
1       "1, 234, 3215"
2       "2, 52, 1"
3       "49, 3"
4       "4"
5
```

desired

```
ID     similar_ids 
1       234, 3215
2       52, 1
3       49
4       
5
```

Comment: Are they actual lists `[1, 234, 3215]`, or strings? `"1, 234, 3215"`

Comment: actual lists- i removed the brackets

Comment: You should keep your data looking exactly how it is, there's no reason to needlessly confuse the reader by removing information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['similar_ids'] = df.apply(lambda row: [x for x in row.similar_ids if x != row.ID], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   ID  similar_ids
0   1  [234, 3215]
1   2      [52, 1]
2   3         [49]
3   4           []
4   5           []
```

Comment: I made an edit to the column format: I double-checked and it looks like it is a string (but quotes wrapped around the numbers)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'ID':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'similar_ids':[[1, 234, 3215], [2, 52, 1], [49, 3], [4], []]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

for i in range(len(df['ID'])):
    if df['ID'][i] in df['similar_ids'][i]:
        df['similar_ids'][i].remove(df['ID'][i])
```

Comment: I made an edit to the column format: I double-checked and it looks like it is a string (but quotes wrapped around the numbers)